# If composition with each functional is bounded, then the operator is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X,Y$ be normed linear spaces and $T:X\to Y$ a linear operator such that for all $\psi\in Y^*$ we have $\psi\circ T\in X^*$. Prove that $T$ is continuous.

There is a "classical approach" of this problem that can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532272/continuous-iff-composition-with-every-linear-functional-is-continuous) as well (See gerw's answer), I had another idea: If we had $X,Y$ being Banach spaces, then this would be quite easy: By the closed graph theorem, it suffices to show that for a sequence $(x_n)\subset X$ with $x_n\to0$ and $Tx_n\to y$, then $y=0$.

For $\psi\in Y^*$ we have $\psi\circ T(x_n)\to0=\psi(y),$ hence $y\in\displaystyle{\bigcap_{\psi\in Y^*}\ker(\psi)=\{0\}}$. This equality is justified by $\|y\|=\displaystyle{\sup_{\|\psi\|_{Y^*}=1}\|\psi(y)\|}$.

I was thinking that if we could embed $X,Y$ in their [completions](http://www.math.udel.edu/~fjsayas/teaching/math806/Completion.pdf), maybe this could work. But we would have to show that $\psi\circ T$ is continuous for the functionals on the completion on $Y$ and we should also extend $T$ to the completion somehow. Do you think that this is possible? Moreover, do you believe that this is a simpler technique, in the sense that it comes more naturally?

Comment: No, I don't see any hope for this. Completeness is essential for the proof and extending $T$ to the completion before knowing that it is continuous is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea works somehow if you take *concrete* completions of your spaces, namely the closure of (the canonical image of) the space in its bidual. The assumption you have precisely means that the transposed $T^*:Y^*\to X^*$ is well defined and (as in gerw's answer to the question you mention) $T^*$ is then continuous. If you restrict $T^{**}: X^{**}\to Y^{**}$ to the closure of $X$ in $X^{**}$ you get an extension of $T$ to the completions (however, it is then needless to refer to the closed graph theorem again because $T^{**}$ is clearly continuous).